# Firebase Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout' Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I run a script weekly. Everything works well when I had less than 9k documents in the collection. I've tried the async function to wait until the foreach end. but it didn't work. Could you help me with the async functions?

Codes:

```
exports.weeklyPointReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('12 04 * * 1').timeZone('UTC').onRun((context) => {


  return db.collection('Users').where('weeklyPoint', '!=', 0).orderBy('weeklyPoint', 'desc').get().then(async (snapshot) => {
    var counter = 1;
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const promises = [];
      await snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        await promises.push(doc.ref.update({ weeklyPoint: 0 }));
      });
      return await Promise.all(promises);
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're returning the `Promise.all()`, get rid of all the superfluous `await` statements and `async` keywords:

```
exports.weeklyPointReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('12 04 * * 1').timeZone('UTC').onRun((context) => {
  return db.collection('Users').where('weeklyPoint', '!=', 0).orderBy('weeklyPoint', 'desc').get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const promises = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        promises.push(doc.ref.update({ weeklyPoint: 0 }));
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  });
});
```

Now each path is (as far as I can see) returning a promise, and the Cloud Functions should terminate at the right moment.

---

Also, I think you can simplify the `else` block to:

```
return Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.ref.update({ weeklyPoint: 0 }));
```

Comment: it didn't work. "Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted."

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frank, my code was the same as you posted but the forEach took a lot of time and then it gave a timeout error, so I added async and await to the my codes. It didn't work as well. My goal is to update the weeklyPoint field in each document to "0", I would be glad if you suggest another solution for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AlesaSeel In addition to the fine tuning advised by Frank, you should try increasing the memory and timeout values, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: Did increasing the memory and timeout values, as Renaud mentioned, solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies. Renaud, I found a way like you mentioned to increase the memory. Solution;

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list,
2. Select the function and then click the edit,
3. Set the memory size and timeout value. (timeout max limit is 540sn)